# Python import error when using PBS

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, python-2.6, pbs

My institute has some parallel computers with CentOS release 6.4 and Python2.6 installed. I want to use python 2.7, then I installed python 2.7.11 locally (without root permission, because I am not a root). My problem is that when I use Portable Batch System (PBS) to run python scripts, some `import` statements raise errors while packages were definitely installed (locally). For more detail, my scripts are:

test.py:

```
import ssl
```

test.pbs:

```
#!/bin/csh
cd working_dir
python test.py
```

1. When I run `python test.py`, no errors displayed.
2. When I submit the PBS job `qsub test.pbs`, the job was started and ended with error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 1, in 
>       import ssl
>     File "/home/s1310007/python/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 97, in 
>       import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
>   ImportError: /home/s1310007/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: symbol SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference

I guess when I ran `python test.py` on the login node (I logged in using `ssh`), the environment paths were set correctly. When the PBS job was started, the different environment paths were set, then the dynamic symbol SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated was not resolved. I tried to modify my `.cshrc` or `.dtprofile`, `.modulesbeginenv`; but nothing works. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: replace your test.py with print os.environ first to see what env you got

Comment: The ` path` environments are the same but in different order. `/home/s1310007/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/intel/itac/9.0.3.051/intel64/bin:/opt/intel/impi/5.0.3.048/intel64/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/bin/intel64_mic:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/debugger/gui/intel64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/ibutils/bin`. This is for the comman `python test.py`

Comment: And this is for the other `/home/s1310007/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/intel/itac/9.0.3.051/intel64/bin:/opt/intel/impi/5.0.3.048/intel64/bin:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/mpirt/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/bin/intel64_mic:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/debugger/gui/intel64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/opt/pbs/default/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/ibutils/bin`

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATHs and LIBRARY_PATHs are the same. I think another possibility is reading permission of the library? But the pbs job should you my account permission, and libssl.so.10 is the system library. Any help please.

Comment: by installing a local copy violated the whole purpose of yum and rpm, to avoid dependency hell,  one last try: qsub -V test.py with import ssl; qsub -I -V

Comment: The problem here seems to be with mismatching versions of libssl on the head and compute nodes. Would your institute let you run docker containers on the nodes?

Comment: @Gang: Thanks but -V does not help me.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: Thanks for that suggestion, I tried to install docker but it seems to require root permission. Let me ask the administrator for this.